# Convert Date to String in Spring 3

Tags: spring, date

I have an entity class with field Date (java.sql.Date, Spring 3). Does somebody know how to convert Date to String (maybe  @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy") ). Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call any of following methods that will return data into string format.

// E.g System.out.println("Date: " + convertDateToString(new Date()));
// E.g System.out.println("Date: " + convertDateToString(new Date(),"dd/MM/yyyy"));

```
public String convertDateToString(Date dt) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dateToString = df.format(dt);
        return dateToString;
    }

public String convertDateToString(Date dt, String pattern) {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            String dateToString = df.format(dt);
            return dateToString;
        }
```

Comment: @user978758 
Thanks for accepting my ans. I would like to share one more thing with you. If u are developing web portal and using PrimeFaces then use following code snippet.                                                  
<h:outputText value="#{abc.date}">
   <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
</h:outputText>

Answer (score 1):

You can register a formatter in a DateFormatterRegistrar that will be used *automagically* whenever you need the string representation of a Date object **for all your date objects**. See [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).

My working example looks like this:

```
public class DateFormatterRegistrar implements FormatterRegistrar {

    @Override
    public void registerFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {

        registry.addFormatter(new DateFormatter("dd-MM-yyyy"));

    }

}
```

then the config is:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/> 

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">

    <property name="formatterRegistrars">
        <set>
            <bean class="path.to.DateFormatterRegistrar" />
        </set>
    </property>

</bean>
```

But then I think they included a spring DateFormatterRegistrar in a more recent version -Have to check-.

The neat thing about this is that it works the other way around as well (converting a String to a Date).

But if what you want is to format only this specific field, the @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")  annotation is the way to go. Just put it before the field in question.